# Intent flags - How to start a new activity instance and have others closed

Tags: android, android-intent, flags

I am not really familiar with intent flags, so please, bear with me.

I am doing an application which displays stuff from a database in a ViewPager. *I also have a widget which from time to time pulls out a random row and displays it. Now, when I click on it, I am taken to an activity where the same content is displayed and now I can take action on it.*

Everything works, however when I have an activity already running and then click on the widget, it seems it creates a new instance, because when I press the Back button I am not exiting the application but am taken to the previous instance or something.

**Is there a way to start a new instance of an activity and if there were some previous instances running close them, using flags?**

I played around with CLEAR_TOP and that stuff but I honestly don't know what am I doing.

Thanks!

//EDIT

Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP doesn't seem to do anything. Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP seems to bring the previous one to the top and ignores the new one or something. Maybe let me rephrase, I start the activity from launcher icon, then I press the Home button and click on widget and it should bring up a new instance where ViewPager.setCurrentItem sets the correct page (same as in widget). If there were no main activity running before, everything is okay, but if it was running, finish it.

```
MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    Log.d("MainActivity", "MyWidgetProvider # onUpdate");

    for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("from_widget", true);
        //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_container, pendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. If you want to create a new instance and close the current instance (assuming that it is on the top of the activity stack) you need to set `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`.

Another alternative would be to reuse the same instance of the activity if it is already on the top of the stack. In this case you need to set **both** `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`. If you do this, Android won't create another instance of the activity, but will call `onNewIntent()` of your activity to deliver the new Intent.

Comment: I edited the question with some code snippets, have a look please.

Comment: As I said, setting CLEAR_TOP and SINGLE_TOP together will cause the same instance of the activity to be used and the framework will call `onNewIntent()` passing the Intent from the widget. You can try also setting NEW_TASK as well. So if you use `setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)` this should create a new instance of `MainActivity`, closing all the others.

Comment: doesnt work, thats weird, can I send you a video or something?

Comment: You can post a video somewhere and put a link to it here if you think that will help. It will also help to post your manifest here for us to look at it.

Comment: Actually intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); does the job, I have no idea how I missed it, probably overworked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Flag other closed,

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
```

And flag new instance,

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```

Answer (score 1):

My requirement was to start activity(AbcActivity) with a new instance and close any other instance of same activity(AbcActivity) if any, and also close other activities on the top(if any). Solution worked for me is:

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,AbcActivity.class)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```