# Android Home Button

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make the up/home button act like the hardware button, I know how to make it visible by including this line:

`getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

Problem is when this button is pressed, the previous activity gets reinitialized and causes my app to crash. The hardware back button works perfectly, it just returns to the previous activity without re-initializing it. How do I accomplish this?

This is how I call my next activity:

`Intent intent = new Intent(context,MenuItemsListActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);`

P.S. I do not think using sharedPreferences is the way to tackle this.

Comment: post your activty code

Comment: Have a look @ http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to pay attention to the way you are launching the Activity in the first place.  If you want it to not get re-initialized, you can set certain flags when you launch it, regarding how the system should handle it.

Here is a good SO with similar concepts discussed: [Intent flags - How to start a new activity instance and have others closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905660/intent-flags-how-to-start-a-new-activity-instance-and-have-others-closed)

Comment: Hi, i think this is what I am looking for, do you have any suggestion on how I should start the activity that has the up button? Which flag must i use to make sure the calling activity doesn't get reinitialized when the up button is pressed on the child button.

Comment: It is what you want, you should research the different options and figure out which is most appropriate for your needs: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html